# (Done) Reopen the Client can no longer pay me due to circumstances question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[client-can-no-longer-afford-to-pay-me-due-to-unforseen-circumstances](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/163784/client-can-no-longer-afford-to-pay-me-due-to-unforseen-circumstances)

A pretty common dilemma and answerable, in fact it has 11 answers already. No idea why it was closed and I think it should be re-opened.

Comment: Funny. This seemed like a Freelancer question, and not at all like a Workplace question to me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the problem is applicable to a business as well, just a matter of scale.

Comment: I suppose. Still seems odd. If this were written from the point of view of an Accounts Payable clerk, would it remain closed?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't see it as an issue that could apply to an AP clerk. But it's one that many small businesses would have had at some point. I have it right now with the COVID 19 lockdowns hurting one whole industry I service.I have contracts so could demand payments, but I'm in for the long run, helping the client get through is worth more in the long term in many ways. It's more a small business issue dealing with small clients than a larger established one.

Comment: To me it's more a "how do I conduct business" issue than a "how do I navigate the workplace" issue. No matter. It's done.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you might be right, but many things are in grey areas or overlap. I just answer anything I think I have useful insight on, don't worry about much else.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the post already had 3 Reopen votes, I cast a 4th and binding vote and the post is open again.